# How to trace Enter in mobile using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('#rollno1').keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    alert('ENTER press');
    //getClassByRollNo();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="rollno1" class="form-control" name="rollno1"/>
```

This code run in website but not run in mobile view

Comment: You need to debug your code for mobile then. Do add alert with "e.which" and check what value you get in alert for mobile enter key. And then detect mobile/website and add code related to it using if/else

Comment: have you tried `keyCode` instead of `which`?